# Android emulator from Android Studio at MacOS changes time continuously

Tags: macos, android-emulator, macos-monterey

I've noticed the Android emulator from Android Studio at MacOS 12.6 changes time to some random one. For example it's 16:11 now but emulator shows time 15:16. If I set time to correct one manually it's changed back to wrong one after some time without emulator being suspended or rebooted.

I tried to turn off all automatic time and zone detection but it didn't help too. Also I'm not sure why wouldn't emulator synchronise time if automatic sync is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a long lasting bug in emulator. The issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/257097404 is created in Google's bug tracker